# Kurento installation getting stuck

Tags: kurento

I am trying install Kurento Media Server. From installation guide in it's official website, I follow:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kurento/kurento
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server
```

Actually, the executing of last command line prompts up a message as below:

```
root@ubuntu:~/build# sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package kurento-media-server is not available, but is referred to by     another package.    This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'kurento-media-server' has no installation candidate
root@ubuntu:~/build#
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 (latest stable version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launchpad only has the deb package for Trusty. If you want to install kurento-media-server in Utopic, you'll have to add Kurento's own repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository http://ubuntu.kurento.org
wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server
```

Comment: Dear @igracia 
Thank to much for your quick reply but I have same message as above after exec last comment :
    sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server.
After running the second command: wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
System said it saves a key OK...???. I have no idea..!!

Comment: @hoanganh17b you need to save that keu, and execute all the commands in the same order

Comment: @hoanganh17b I have just installed a VM in VirtualBox with Ubuntu 14.10, in order to check that it's working. Check your _/etc/apt/sources.list_ to see if you have a line like this _deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org utopic main_

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way ( It works for me ) is running Kurento Media Server on Trusty..Ubuntu 14.02. I didn't see any alternation could help me run it on Utopic

Answer (score 0):

Kurento Media Server Installation
Kurento Media Server (KMS) has to be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bits).

In order to install the latest stable Kurento Media Server version (6.0.0) you have to type the following commands, one at a time and in the same order as listed here. When asked for any kind of confirmation, reply affirmatively:

```
echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

Take into account that if your are installing Kurento Media Server in Ubuntu Server 14.04, the tool add-apt-repository is not installed by default. To install it, run this command:

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
Now, Kurento Media Server has been installed and started. Use the following commands to start and stop it respectively:

```
sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 stop
```

Comment: So, how about  Ubuntu 14.10??.. @Jijo Paulose

Comment: Right now  Kurento Media Server only support Ubuntu 14.04 .

Answer (score 0):

I use oficial docker image for it. Works in production, all fine.
If you can use docker, get images of kurento here

[kurento docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/kurento/kurento-media-server/)

One command, and kurento server starts

```
$ docker run --name kms -p 8888:8888 -d
```

kurento/kurento-media-server

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This answer doesn't really relate to the question, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.